# reading from a file, input string is incorrect C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a file from a .txt, the file is a few numbers. But when I run the program I'm getting input string is not in the correct format. I passed everything into integers using parse. What am I missing?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            const int Size = 10; 
            int[] numbers = new int[Size];

            int index = 0; 

            StreamReader inputFile; 

            inputFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

            while(index < numbers.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                numbers[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                index++;
            }
            inputFile.Close();

            foreach( int value in numbers)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(value);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the sample data inside of ``inputFile?``

Comment: 1245.67
1189.55
1098.72
1456.88
2109.34
1987.55
1872.36

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your input file consisting of `double`s, not `int`s. Any non-whole number must be stored as a `double` or a `float` if you do not want to lose the numbers after the decimal point. Try the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        const int Size = 10; 
        double[] numbers = new double[Size];

        int index = 0; 

        StreamReader inputFile; 

        inputFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

        while(index < numbers.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            numbers[index] = double.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
            index++;
        }
        inputFile.Close();

        foreach(double value in numbers)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, the issue may also be that your data isn't separated by lines, but by spaces. According to your comment, this may be the case. To fix that, you would use the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (double value in File.ReadAllText("Sales.txt").Split(' ').Select((x) => (double.Parse(x))))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What this solution does is `ReadAllText` from the file, which automatically handles streams, opening, and closing of the file. I pass that into the `Split` function, which splits a single `String` into substrings where the parameter is found. So, if you have `123.613 7342.152` as your `String`, it will return you a `String[]` that consists of `123.613` and `7342.152`. However, these values are still `String`s. We still need to parse them into numbers. We can do this by using the LINQ `Select` operator, and passing it in a lambda that will call `double.Parse(...)` on the value and return it as an `IEnumerable<double>`.

Comment: I switched it over to double instead of integer, and it worked out. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!